# Logout por inactividad despues de 5min con kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Quiero hacer logout despues de 5min de inactividad, tengo este codigo, apenas empiezo con apps moviles y no entiendo muy bien el como fuinciona ya que con mi codigo no realiza el logout(ni hace nada :( ), no entiendo si mi codigo deberia implementarlo(mandarlo llamar desde alguna otra activity) ya que esto no sucede al seleccionar un boton o algo debe ser por inactividad, entonces como es que se ejecuta?, al ejecutar mi app no me manda error pero tampoco lo realiza(lo demas en mi app funciona bien)

```
class Logout : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var personasService: PersonasService

private var lastInteractionTime: Long = 0
private val INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 5 * 60 * 1000 // 5 minutos en milisegundos
private val CHECK_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000 // Intervalo de verificación cada minuto

private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())


private val checkRunnable = object : Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        Log.d("CERRAR SESION","INGRESA LOGOUT FUN RUN")

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - lastInteractionTime >= INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT) {
          
           var request: CerrarSessionRequest = CerrarSessionRequest(false)
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
               val response = personasService.cerrarSession(request)
                Log.d("CERRAR SESION", "El usuario cierra sesion por inactividad")

               Log.d("RESPONSE CERRAR SESION", response.message)


                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
            applicationContext.startActivity(intent)

        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, CHECK_INTERVAL.toLong())
    }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("CERRAR SESION","INGRESA LOGOUT FUN ONCREATE")

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, LoginActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK 
    applicationContext.startActivity(intent)


    // Iniciar el temporizador de verificación de inactividad
    handler.postDelayed(checkRunnable, CHECK_INTERVAL.toLong())
}

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    Log.d("CERRAR SESION","INGRESA LOGOUT FUN DISPATCH")

    // Reiniciar el temporizador cada vez que el usuario interactúe con la aplicación
    lastInteractionTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}

override fun onStop() {
    Log.d("CERRAR SESION","INGRESA LOGOUT FUN ONSTOP")

    super.onStop()
    // Detener la ejecución del temporizador al detener la actividad
    handler.removeCallbacks(checkRunnable)
}
```

}